# How to merge two rows if same values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the Following Output:

| **Sno** | **Value Stream** | **Duration** | **Inspection** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | ON | 14 | 0 |
| 3 | Start | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | Test1 | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | OFF | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | Start | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | Test2 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | ON | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | START | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | Test2 | 2 | 2 |

I want to merge the same value after that before START values charge to after ON. For example S.no 4 will merge to s.no4.

```
1    |    Test1    |      8     |   2      |
```

If the combination is not equal then don't allow it to merge. For Example, we have to consider only On/Start. If the condition is OFF/Start then don't allow to merge. E.g. S.no 5 and 6 OFF/Start then don't allow to merge s.no 4 & 7.

Comment: Your description on the issue is not clear.  What do you mean by `merge the same value` (what value ?), `S.no 4 will merge to s.no4.`, `IF the combination not equal` (what combination ? equal to what ?). Please consider to re-phrase it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about summarization not merging:

```
select [Value Stream],
min(Sno) as First_Sno,
sum(Duration) as total_Duration,
sum(Inspection) as Inspection
from yourtable
group by [Value Stream]
```

Will give you the result